# Selected png images to gif using ffmpeg or imagemagick

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

I want to convert png to gif and i want to mention which are the frames i want to combine
eg: frame1.png and frame2.png.
I've tried using `ffmpeg -i frames/%03d.png -vf fps=20 logo.gif` but it is considering all the images in that directory, but i want only two images in that directory to be included in the gif i want to create. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ones you want:

```
magick -delay 80 nice1.png nice37.png animated.gif
```

---

By way of explanation and further example, I can make a red and a blue frame and morph between the two in 14 steps like this - making a total of 16 frames:

```
magick -size 20x100 xc:red xc:blue -morph 14 frame-%02d.png
```

If I append those frames side-by-side, you can see them all:

```
magick frame* +append side-by-side.png
```

[image]

And I can list them in the shell:

```
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-00.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-01.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-02.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-03.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-04.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-05.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-06.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-07.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-08.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-09.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-10.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-11.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-12.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-13.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-14.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       278 28 Apr 13:45 frame-15.png
```

If I now want to select some to make an animated GIF, I can use the shell's *"brace expansion"* to select certain ones:

```
ls frame-0{2,3,9}.png
frame-02.png    frame-03.png    frame-09.png
```

Or the shell's *"range expansion"* to select a contiguous range:

```
ls frame-1[2-4].png
frame-12.png    frame-13.png    frame-14.png
```

Or the shell's *"wildcard expansion"*:

```
ls frame-1?.png
frame-10.png    frame-11.png    frame-12.png    frame-13.png    frame-14.png    frame-15.png
```

And that works with `magick` just the same as `ls`, so I can select a few frames for an animated GIF like this:

```
magick -delay 80 frame-0{2,4}.png frame-1*.png animated.gif
```

[image]

Comment: `magick -delay 80 nice1.png nice37.png animated.gif` helped me...thank you and is there a way to make it loop only once?

Comment: Should be `magick -loop 1 ...` Bear in mind that not all viewers respect it.